# using ajax delete records form mysql

Tags: php

tell me with good example
how can delete records form database table using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP with code to delete records from database. Let's say `delete.php` (example extracted from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp)):

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Persons WHERE LastName='Griffin'");
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Then, do a `GET` or a `POST` with Ajax to `delete.php`. An example would be:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://yourdomain.com/delete.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

You can send parameters if you need to `delete.php` on the `open` call to `xmlhttp`. Take examples on how to do that from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

As @Davide suggested in the comments, it might be a better idea to use `POST` commands instead of `GET` to perform this kind of operation.

Comment: It's better to use POST if you want to modify the database, GET is fine if you only need to read it.

Comment: @Davide: can you elaborate why? I can't think of any disadvantage of using get. The only one could be **caching** issues... But even that can be fixed with a random variable...

Comment: For example, search engine crawlers could decide to visit your delete.php page and make some damage :)

Comment: @Davide: that's a very good point. Do you think crawlers crawl even URLs found in JavaScript code? But very good point.

Comment: I'm not sure if crawlers are following URLs in javascript code, but I wouldn't take the chance...